# Spring Data Repository Async Save

Tags: spring, asynchronous, spring-data-redis

I have a service using Spring Data Redis and the `CrudRepository`, and within one of my service methods it performs a query and then a save. I want to make the save asynchronous. Is it possible to make the save method in my extended `CrudRepository` asynchronous?

With the example below I want the `save` operation to be asynchronous.

```
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String> {
    public List<User> findByUserId(Long userId);
}

public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    public void addUser(User newUser) {
        List<User> users = myRepository.findByUserId(newUser.getUserId());
        // other operations on users
        myRepository.save(); // want this be async
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare `save` method again in `MyRepository` and add annotate it with `@Async`.

```java
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String> {
    public List<User> findByUserId(Long userId);
    @Async
    public <S extends User> S save(S entity);
}
```

Comment: Does it not need to have a return type of Future?

Comment: This way, if @Async is setup correctly, you will always get null in return.

Comment: How to get a Future<S> in this ?

Comment: @Async
 <S extends User> Future<S> save(final User user);